# Is it possible to record an Android screen with Python?

Tags: android, python, video, video-recording

I seek advice

Is it possible to record an Android screen with Python?

This is what I want to implement

1. Python will record your Android screen.
2. Print the error log.

Do you know ddms? I want to implement this in Python. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: You want to run a screen recorder that captures the Android screen(in your device) or in your monitor ?

Comment: @VineethSai No. I want to record the phone screen in a pc application after connecting my computer and smartphone with usb.  I want to make that computer application using by python

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly implement something like this with adb, run

```
adb exec-out screencap > screen.dump
```

The above command gives you the the raw pixel data on screen in the file `screen.dump`. To record video, you could run the above command in a loop.
You could use [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) to process the raw data.

I am not sure how fast this approach would be, people more familiar with adb could provide a better solution.

Comment: I just found out about the `adb screenrecord` command, you could give that a try.